# OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django

hey guys, im using django 1.2.1 , and python 2.4, also i have django cms 2.1.3 beta, im using virtual hosts in my apache conf, for some reason everytime i add a new content, like text, or pictures, i get a OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded, what causes this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Disk quota exceeded` says it all: there is no space left **for you** on the drive.

DjangoCMS uses `FileStorage` to store images. For text, however, it should use the db. Did you configure it correctly? Adding text only should not yield you that error.

As for images, you probably just need more space from your provider. Or, if you have an extra partition or something you could use, you could set up the `FileStorage` instance tu put your stuff there.